# Assigning a function to an array element in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am currently working on a homework assignment where we use void functions to print information.

Our teacher wants us to do this:

> Demonstrate the class in a program that has a Ship Array. Assign
>   various Ship, CruiseShip, and CargoShip objects to the array elements.
>   The program should then step through the array, calling the object’s
>   printInfo method."

```
Ship ob1;               // object of ship class     CruiseShip ob2;         // object of
cruiseship class    CargoShip ob3;          // object of cargoship class

typedef void((*shipArray)());   // declaring

   void(*ob1)() = ob1.printInfo;    // pointer to print info function in
 ship class     void(*ob2)() = ob2.printInfo;   // pointer to print info
 function in cruiseship class   void(*ob3)() = ob3.printInfo;   // pointer
 to print info function in cargoship class

    shipArray ship[3] = {ob1.printInfo, ob2.printInfo, ob3.printInfo};  //
 array assigns the functions to each 

element


   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)      // loop to output each function     {
cout << ship[i] << endl << endl;    }
```

How do I accomplish this? I am stuck...

Comment: This site is not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I dont need anyone to do my homework. I just need to know the fix to get arrays to work with void functions...

Comment: Then add that to the original question.

Comment: 1. post a MCVE, 2. explain what's not working (including any error messages)

Comment: The MCVE @M.M is referring to is a [mcve].

Comment: C2373 is the error message from visual studio. It has to do with the part of code containing the objects. I've googled the error message, but Microsoft is rather vague (or to me it seems so) for possible solutions.

Comment: You have an array of objects, and you just do `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) someArray[i].printInfo();`. or `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) someArray[i]->printInfo();` if you have an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions say that the array should contain ships, not function pointers. However, to avoid object slicing, it needs to be an array of pointers. You need:

```
Ship *ships[] = {&obj1, &obj2, &obj3};
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ships)/sizeof(*ships); i++) {
    ship[i]->printInfo();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is somewhat guiding me in the direction I was headed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your functions in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // loop to output each function 
{ 
     cout << ship[i]() << endl << endl; 
}
```